# How come I can't resize Google Chrome's window less than 595px?

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason I can not resize Chrome's window to less than 595 px on Ubuntu 12.10. I can resize Firefox's window to 0 px. Also I can resize the Chrome window to a very small size on Windows. This is an important issue when it comes to web design and more specifically responsive webdesign where resizing the window to at least 320px plays an important role.

**Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?**

Comment: confirmed it. I can resize firefox to the point where I can barely see it, however Chrome and Chromium both have that minimum width. Weird...I'm inclined that there is something in the source code that causes it. But it seems odd that the windows port doesn't behave the same.

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer, but according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874609/which-gui-library-does-google-chrome-use) on stackexchange, Chrome uses a different GUI library for Windows, Mac, and Linux. So the code for the graphical interface for chrome for those 3 systems are different and written from scratch.

Comment: I just figured it out. You can only shrink the window to the width of the top nav icon width. So the window wont shrink past the back, forward, refresh, home, extension buttons(in the URL bar + to the right of the URL bar) and settings button. If I disable all my extensions I can get the window pretty thin.

Comment: odd though, firefox uses the gtk+ library and it doesn't have a minimum width for its elements. There is bound to be something in the google chrome source code that you could alter to change this behaviour. Though if this is the case, this really isn't a question for askubuntu...

Comment: This isn't a Ubuntu or Linux specific problem, it happens with Windows as well.

Answer (score 12):

If for some reason you want to use Google Chrome and not Firefox for responsive work, we can utilize the Chrome Debugger to achieve this, below are the steps -

1. Click F12 to open debugger in Google Chrome.
2. Click the 'Dock to main window' button which is at the bottom left of debugger and arrange your debugger window so it's vertically aligned on the right side of your application.
3. Now you can move the separator line between your application and debugger to re-size the application to whatever responsive width you want.

Let me know if you need more details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is just disappointing.

Comment: This is a workaround but not an answer to the question.

Comment: Tip: Use `ctrl + shift + d` to switch between "docker to window" and "dock to right".

Answer (score 3):

This is not an Ubuntu dependant issue but a Chrome work environment one. There are some constraints on resizing the Chrome windows width to a minimum measure.

*- Disclaimer: all measures are empiric, approximate and manual -*

Omnibox seems to take a minimum width of 256px, plus the width taken by the back, forward, refresh and menu buttons restrict in my case the window to a minimum width of 390px. Also, every pinned tab you have increment the minimum width by a non-constant measure of pixels. In past versions the number os showing extensions also used to affect, although currently they hide/show automatically on resize. I haven't found more workspace related variables which alter the window minimum width but I will post here as I discover them.

Feedback is welcome [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707745&can=1&q=window%20width&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).